# Html, dynamic external link

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

Using html and javascript i want to have an

```
<a href="externallink">text<\a>
```

However i would like the link to be stored in another document, which will then be updated regularly. Is there a way that the href can link to the link in the other document?

Ive been playing with javascript but could not achieve this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dont you want to use template binding libraries like Knockout or angular to fetch the template in your page?